# Drupal getting news image via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, drupal

I am trying to retrieve the images from my Drupal nodes but I keep getting '0' is undefined. I am getting the articles from my own Drupal page.

```
for(var i =0;i<news.length;i++)
{
    var article = 
                [
                    news[i].node.Nid + '-'+ lang,
                    newsCount,
                    d.getMilliseconds(),
                    news[i].node.title,
                    news[i].node.date,
                    news[i].node.Featured_image[0].src,
                    lang,
                    news[i].node.Body
                ];
    var url = decodeURIComponent(news[i].node.Featured_image);          
    ImgCache.cacheFile(url);
    articles.push(article);
}
```

So I tried this...

```
for(var i =0;i<news.length;i++)
{
    if (typeof news[i].node.Featured_image == undefined)
    {
        news_image = news[i].node.Featured_image;
    }
    else
    {
        news_image = image;
    } 

    var article = 
                [
                    news[i].node.Nid + '-'+ lang,
                    newsCount,
                    d.getMilliseconds(),
                    news[i].node.title,
                    news[i].node.date,
                    news_image,
                    lang,
                    news[i].node.Body
                ];
    var url = decodeURIComponent(news_image);
    ImgCache.cacheFile(url);
    articles.push(article);
}
```

But it seems all images are undefined. No idea why. Hope you can help me.

Comment: did you try to `console.log(news);` and see in console if you have data expected ?

Comment: Yep I tried it. Seems it was Featured_Image than Featured_image. My mistake